# Hide scrollbar in LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8, scrollbar, longlistselector

I'm using a LongListSelector and the scrollbar on the right is adding a bit of empty space which is messing up the design, so I want to hide it. I've tried the following:

```
ScrollBar sb = ((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(FileList, 0))
                           .FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
sb.Width = 0;
```

But that's not working for wp8, I can make the width larger though but not smaller. It has a ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility property but changing it to Hidden or Disabled doesn't do anything.

/Edit:

This appears to work:

```
var sb = ((FrameworkElement) VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(FileList, 0))
.FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
sb.Margin = new Thickness(-10, 0, 0, 0);
```

But if anyone has a cleaner method I would still like to hear it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 - LongListSelector, how to hide vertical scroll bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131496/wp7-longlistselector-how-to-hide-vertical-scroll-bar)

Comment: @caschw It's not the same, that's where I found the first method which doesn't work on wp8.

Comment: After digging through the methods and control hierarchy, there isn't anything strictly "cleaner." The only changes you could make are to set the scrollbar Width to 0 and Margin to new Thickness() without parameters for a 0 margin.

Comment: @lthibodeaux setting the Width and Margin to 0 does not eliminate the empty space entirely. It does when it's negative.

Comment: I have a similar issue. What has worked for me is to wrap the LLS into a ScrollViewer tag and setting that tag's VerticalScrollBarVisibility to "Hidden". This does the effect nicely, however when I tried to modify the last later (re-assign it) I got a layout cycle error. Your method works for me, I wish it were cleaner, but perhaps the ScrollViewer tag may help yours.

Answer (score 6):

You can address this by retemplating the whole control.

Add this resource:

```
<Style x:Key="LongListSelectorWithNoScrollBarStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ViewportControl x:Name="ViewportControl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Use the resource

```
<phone:LongListSelector Style="{StaticResource LongListSelectorWithNoScrollBarStyle}">
    ....
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Voila. No scrollbar.

Comment: What import line do I need in my xaml for it to be able to recognize `d:DesignWidth` and `d:DesignHeight`?